# Powershell param just doesn't work and it's driving me nuts

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to use param within Powershell 5
My script is as following:

```
param(
[parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[string]$IP,

[parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[string]$Time
)
Write-Host $IP
Write-Host $Time
```

Suppose the script is named test.ps1,
I tried running it in 2 ways:

```
.\test.ps1 -IP 10.10.10.10 -Time 10:10
.\test.ps1 -IP "10.10.10.10" -Time "10:10"
```

None of these work.
Instead, it prompts me to enter a value to IP.
The error is as following:

```
cmdlet test.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
IP:
```

Obviously this little script is just a phase in integrating a piece of code into a bigger script system.
Help would be appreciated, after hours of searching I don't see what I've done wrong.

Comment: Works fine for me, copying and pasting your script: http://i.imgur.com/1NKn9AL.png  are you running it from a command prompt or on a remote machine or anything? What's the bigger system?

Comment: Can confirm that it is working for me as well.  Can you maybe post some screenshots of how your calling the code and what your seeing?

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm this runs on my computer.  I had to switch directories to the (ex: cd (directory where script is located). directory where the .ps1 script is located.  I ran this from the Windows command window.

```
powershell.exe .\test.ps1 -IP "10.10.10.10" -Time "10:10"
```

This should work as well.

```
powershell -File C:\somedirectory\test.ps1 -IP "10.10.10.10" -Time "10:10"
```

Can kick this off via a .bat file as well.  Such as test.bat

```
In command prompt C:\>test.bat "10.10.10.10" "10:10"
```

Contents of .bat file below.

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell -File C:\somedirectory\test.ps1 -IP %1 -Time %2
```